# Internet Explorer and JSON

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer, parse-error

I'm having a strange behavior with IE.
In development environment the JSON calls work perfectly, while in production they fail due to "parsererror" even with a status code of 200.
I've seen other messages here in stackoverflow, but I'm posting since I have this different behaviours between two environments.

DEV Environment: Ubuntu / Tomcat 6.026

Prod environment: Win 2003 server / Tomcat 6.0.33

Comment: So you open the JSON in IE and IE itself gives a parser error? If so, what version(s) of IE are we talking about?

Comment: IE9. If you want to have a look: www . gambadv . it (without white spaces). I perform an AJAX request (using jQuery) to an underlying web service that produces JSON response (an array of objects). Then the error hook is invoked and the error I see is "parsererror". I've yet tried to add / remove response headers such as content-type or charset but the behavior doesn't change.

Comment: If I call directly the service URL from the browser, I get the expected response. The JSON produced doesn't seem malformed (I'm using Spring Framework, I don't format the JSON response by myself)

Comment: The JSON can indeed can correctly parsed by Firebug. I'm getting "Cannot connect parsererror"; are you creating that alert somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating the alert in the error hook of the jQuery.ajax function (hope you can read).
`code $.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : callEndpoint(projectServiceUrl, "paged", true),
  data : {
   "pageNumber" : page,
   "pageSize" : pageSize
  },
  contentType: "application/json; charset:utf-8",
  cache: false,
  dataType : "json",
  success : function(result) {
   loadVisionsOnDom(result);
  },
  error : function(x, e) {
   alert("Cannot connect\n" + e);
  }
 });`

Comment: Solved. Added both content-type and charset to the response header via Spring WEB MVC annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding content-type and charset to the @RequestMapping annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paged", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json; charset=utf-8")
```